# How to boot to root shell with Rasperry Pi using the Ubuntu server image

Tags: 19.10, raspberrypi

I can't interrupt the boot to get to a root shell of Raspberry 4 built using ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img. Holding shift, as with NOOBS, doesn't work.